# Reading data matrix from text file in Julia

Tags: matrix, input, julia, file-read

I have text file which includes a matrix. I want to read it in julia as a matrix.

The text file is like:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

In matlab you can do the following to create matrix `M` :

```
file='name.txt';
[M] = load(file);
```

How to do same thing in Julia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read into arrays in Julia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295276/read-into-arrays-in-julia)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
shell> cat /tmp/m.txt
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   0   1   1   0

using DelimitedFiles

julia> m = readdlm("/tmp/m.txt")
4x7 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: you can `readdlm` into Julia without having to `cat` the file first.

Comment: For anyone not familiar with julia: you need first to include DelimitedFiles as follows `using DelimitedFiles` in order to use `readdlm`